# (SQLITE) How to add together sums from another table using a subquery

Tags: sqlite

I'm going through an introduction to SQL, and I'm struggling to approach this problem. I've simplified it down to two tables below:

```
Purchases                                                                         
+------------+-------+
| CustomerID | Price |   
+------------+-------+
| 1          | 3.76  |
+------------+-------+
| 3          | 1.89  |
+------------+-------+
| 2          | 2.22  |
+------------+-------+
| 2          | 3.76  |
+------------+-------+
| 2          | 7.90  |
+------------+-------+
| 1          | 4.51  |
+------------+-------+

Location
+------------+------------+
| CustomerID | County     |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | Orange     |
+------------+------------+
| 2          | Washington |
+------------+------------+
| 3          | Orange     |
+------------+------------+
```

Now, let's say I wanted to display the sum of all purchases in each county. Like so:

```
+------------+-------+
| County     | Sum   |
+------------+-------+
| Orange     | 10.16 |
+------------+-------+
| Washington | 13.88 |
+------------+-------+
```

I understand the basics of getting the sum for each client,

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Price)
FROM Purchases
GROUP by CustomerID
```

but I struggle with syntax when trying to use a subquery to implement the other table.

```
select County, CustomerID
from Location as cty,
  SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Price)
  FROM Purchases
  GROUP by CustomerID
```

I'm trying to establish a connection between the clientIDs in both tables but I get mixed up when trying to do it. How would I implement the second sum statement (for the counties)? Is this the wrong way to approach the problem, or do I not properly understand subqueries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that?

```
SELECT n.County, SUM(p.Price) Price
FROM Purchases p
JOIN Location n
ON p.CustomerID=n.CustomerID
GROUP BY n.County
```

Comment: Yup! Guess I was forcing myself into a box with subqueries. I'll read up more on JOIN statements.